# Angular 2 - How to add permalink?

Tags: angular2-routing, permalinks

I try to add permalinks to my angular 2 app, but I didn't find a way yet.

My app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: TagelerComponent },
  { path: 'tageler', component: TagelerListComponent },
  { path: 'tageler-details/:id', component: TagelerDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'group/:id', component: GroupDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'tageler/admin', component: AdminComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And my code looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groups | groupTypeFilter: 'Trupp' ">
    <a  routerLink="/group/{{group._id}}">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{group.name}}
      </li>
    </a>
</div>
```

In this example the URL is something like: http://localhost:4200/group/5910c2282249261cc61d0a7e

Instead of the group id, I would like to display the name of the group (e.g. dogs) without changing the routing, so the URL changes to: 'http://localhost:4200/group/dogs'.

I'm new to Angular 2, so I don't really know whether this is actually possible.

I would be glad if someone could help me!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **you can not** replace the id with the name in the routerLink, and then query the group by id, assume a user opened a new tab and entered the URL

`http://localhost:4200/group/dogs`

The app will load and the only reference you have is `dogs`, where will the id come from? unless you have already defined a dictionary that returns the id of the given group name, or by using some black magic

However in case you only let the user to access the detail page through its parent, then you can pass the group instance by using a shared service and set the router link to `group.name`.

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groups | groupTypeFilter: 'Trupp' ">
  <a [routerLink]="shared.setGroupLink(group)">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      {{group.name}}
    </li>
  </a>
</div>

constructor(public shared: SharedService) { }
```

in *SharedService*

```
export class SharedService{

   currGroupId: number;

   constructor() { }

   setGroupLink(group) {
      // you can pass the object as a whole but I'll use `group.id` in this example
      // this.currGroup = group;
      this.currGroupId = group.id;
      return '/group/' + group.name;
   }
}
```

In *GroupDetailsComponent*

```
groupId: number;

constructor(public shared: SharedService) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.groupId = this.shared.currGroupId;
}
```

**NOTE:** this approach will not work if the user entered `http://localhost:4200/group/dogs` because `groupId` is undefined

by the way, avoid prefixing your variables' names with the underscore `_`, check [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#03-04)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it! Do you know whether there is an approach that will also work if the user entered 'http://localhost:4200/group/dogs'?